# Parsing a string to boolean in java

Tags: java, variables, boolean

I have the following simple sales program and am having trouble creating a restart loop around the program.  My primary issue is converting the boolean from a string to a boolean type, I am getting an error in Eclipse that says, "The method parseBoolean(String) is undefined for the type Boolean".

However, I have defined a boolean variable at the top, boolean tryAgain = false;

and for some reason I cannot set the user input scanner to take the True or False value without an error.  The error is occurring with the last line when I try to cast the nextLine from the user to boolean.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sales {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String item1, item2, item3;                 //Three vars for items
        double price1, price2, price3;              //Three vars for price
        int quantity1, quantity2, quantity3;        //Three vars for quantity
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates scanner for user input
        double sum;                                 //var for total before tax
        double tax;                                 //var for tax
        double total;                               //var for total with tax
        double tax_total;                           //var to calculate tax
        boolean tryAgain = true;                    //boolean for try again loop to restart program

        // First set of inputs

        while (tryAgain) {

            System.out.println("Please enter the first item: ");
            item1 = userInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the price of the first item: ");
            price1 = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity purchased: ");
            quantity1 = userInput.nextInt();

            // Second set of inputs

            System.out.println("Please enter the second item: ");
            item2 = userInput.next(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the price of the second item: ");
            price2 = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity purchased: ");
            quantity2 = userInput.nextInt();

            // Third set of inputs

            System.out.println("Please enter the third item: ");
            item3 = userInput.next(); //skipping over item 2.  Why?
            System.out.println("Please enter the price of the third item: ");
            price3 = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity purchased: ");
            quantity3 = userInput.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please enter the sales tax rate: ");            //Prompt user for tax rate
            tax = userInput.nextDouble();

            //Print line item totals

            System.out.println("Line item totals");
            System.out.println("____________________");
            System.out.println("Item 1: " + item1 + "\t" + "$" + price1);
            System.out.println("Item 2: " + item2 + "\t" + "$" + price2);
            System.out.println("Item 3: " + item3 + "\t" + "$" + price3);
            System.out.println();

            //Process final output for display

            sum = price1 + price2 + price3;
            total = (sum * tax) + sum;
            tax_total = tax * sum;
            System.out.println("Total cost(no tax):\t" + "$" + sum);                    //display total cost witout tax
            System.out.println("Total tax(" + tax + " rate): \t" + "$" + tax_total);    //display total tax
            System.out.println("Total cost(with tax):\t" + "$" + total);                //display total with tax
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Program created by James Bellamy");

            System.out.println("Do you want to run the program again? (True or False)");

            tryAgain = Boolean.parseBoolean(userInput.nextLine());

        }




    }

}
```

Comment: Have you defined a class named `Boolean`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it gives you trouble is that when the user enters a double then hits enter, two things have just been entered - the double and a "newline" which is \n.

The method you are calling, "nextDouble()", only reads in the double, which leaves the newline in the input stream. But calling nextLine() does read in newlines, which is why you have to call nextLine() before your code would work.

Add this line before last line .

```
userInput.nextLine();
```

Comment: @chrylis There is no compilation error in the code. Please check again Boolean is java defined class and it has a parseBoolean method, so there is no compilation error. Can you show me what compilation error you are getting ?

Comment: Read the question: `The method parseBoolean(String) is undefined for the type Boolean`

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for the feedback.  I did as Narayan said, which worked - it took the input.  But, the program hangs terminates when the user enters true, which is not what I want.  Why is it terminating?  It should go to the top and continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't get it to work with a boolean for some reason, so I changed to a do while loop.  Here is the final code.  Also I did use the tip for clearing out the nextLine().

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sales2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String item1, item2, item3;                 //Three vars for items
        double price1, price2, price3;              //Three vars for price
        int quantity1, quantity2, quantity3;        //Three vars for quantity
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates scanner for user inputjea
        double sum;                                 //var for total before tax
        double tax;                                 //var for tax
        double total;                               //var for total with tax
        double tax_total;                           //var to calculate tax
        boolean tryAgain = true;                    //boolean for try again loop to restart program

        // First set of inputs

        String answer;                              //Define var type of String for do while loop to restart program
        do {                                        //Do this loop while string == (last line of code while loop)

            System.out.println("Please enter the first item: ");
            item1 = userInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the price of the first item: ");
            price1 = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity purchased: ");
            quantity1 = userInput.nextInt();

            // Second set of inputs

            System.out.println("Please enter the second item: ");
            item2 = userInput.next(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the price of the second item: ");
            price2 = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity purchased: ");
            quantity2 = userInput.nextInt();

            // Third set of inputs

            System.out.println("Please enter the third item: ");
            item3 = userInput.next(); //skipping over item 2.  Why?
            System.out.println("Please enter the price of the third item: ");
            price3 = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity purchased: ");
            quantity3 = userInput.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please enter the sales tax rate: ");            //Prompt user for tax rate
            tax = userInput.nextDouble();

            //Print line item totals

            System.out.println("Line item totals");
            System.out.println("____________________");
            System.out.println("Item 1: " + item1 + "\t" + "$" + price1);
            System.out.println("Item 2: " + item2 + "\t" + "$" + price2);
            System.out.println("Item 3: " + item3 + "\t" + "$" + price3);
            System.out.println();

            //Process final output for display

            sum = price1 + price2 + price3;
            total = (sum * tax) + sum;
            tax_total = tax * sum;
            System.out.println("Total cost(no tax):\t" + "$" + sum);                    //display total cost witout tax
            System.out.println("Total tax(" + tax + " rate): \t" + "$" + tax_total);    //display total tax
            System.out.println("Total cost(with tax):\t" + "$" + total);                //display total with tax
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Program created by James Bellamy");

            System.out.println("Do you want to run the program again? (yes or no)");    //Prompt user for restart
            userInput.nextLine();                                                       //Clear scanner 
            answer = userInput.nextLine();

        }
        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));                                         //Connected to do while loop
                                                                                        //




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` supports `nextBoolean()`. Just use it:

```
tryAgain = userInput.nextBoolean()
```